# Cannot deploy application - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I am trying to deploy an early version application I made but I get this stack trace when I install it. Can anyone suggest anything?

I looked around the assembly in Visual Studio but couldn't find the right setting. I doubt it is that much to do with the assembly.

This is the error message I get when I install the application:

> ERROR DETAILS
>
> Following errors were detected during this operation.
>       * [20/05/2019 1:58:37 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (ComponentStore)
>           - Exception occurred during store operation.
>           - Source: System.Deployment
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.SubmitStoreTransaction(StoreTransactionContext storeTxn, SubscriptionState subState)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.SetPendingDeployment(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionIdentity deployId, DateTime checkTime)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.SetLastCheckTimeToNow(SubscriptionState subState)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>               at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
>           --- Inner Exception ---
>           System.ArgumentException
>           - Value does not fall within the expected range.
>           - Source: System.Deployment
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.Transact(IntPtr cOperation, StoreTransactionOperation[] rgOperations, UInt32[] rgDispositions, Int32[] rgResults)
>               at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store.Transact(StoreTransactionOperation[] operations, UInt32[] rgDispositions, Int32[] rgResults)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.SubmitStoreTransaction(StoreTransactionContext storeTxn, SubscriptionState subState)

Here is some more information

> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS * Transaction at [21/05/2019 12:08:38 PM] + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata - Status: Set - HRESULT: 0x0 + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27) - HRESULT: 0x80070057

**EDIT:** I found the ClickOnce store and also changed the version number of the project because it was wrong. Now **the installer ITSELF crashes to this stack trace (which is a good sign):**

> ERROR DETAILS
>
> Following errors were detected during this operation.
>       * [21/05/2019 2:22:31 PM] System.ArgumentException
>           - Value does not fall within the expected range.
>           - Source: System.Deployment
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>               at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
>       No transaction information is available.

Can anyone fix it now?

**EDIT 2:
I sort of fixed it by wiping the ClickOnce store as originally directed (but must have deleted the wrong files originally), but I lost all my data although it can be fixed by copying the folders back in. It would be nice to know what exactly was broken though.**

**EDIT 3:**
It broke one of my former projects. I fixed that by deleting the certificate, but I wonder if there was another way.

Comment: Do you get this error whilst it is installing for the first time or whilst running it?

Comment: I get this error when I install it. It is a ClickOnce application.

Comment: Can you post your click-once settings?

Comment: How do you want me to do that?

Comment: Here is some more information


COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
 * Transaction at [21/05/2019 12:08:38 PM]
  + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
   - Status: Set
   - HRESULT: 0x0
  + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
   - HRESULT: 0x80070057

Comment: @Fildor made some changes.

Comment: I have incorporated your last comment into your question.  **TIP:**  Did you know you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56214195/edit) your question by clicking the **edit** link above to include new details rather than post as a comment (where it might get missed).  Wishing you well and good luck.  Hope someone is able to help

Comment: I think Fildor means can you take screenshots of your  ClickOnce **Publish** settings from within Visual Studio.  Now as a StackOverflow user of ~18 reputation, any images you post won't appear for you, rather just the hyperlink,  but others will be able to fix it for you.

Comment: I fixed it by wiping the ClickOnce store, but I lost all my data although it can be fixed by copying the folders back in. It would be nice to know what exactly was broken though.

Comment: @MickyD You put it in the wrong spot. I fixed it.

Comment: I dont think it matters in the scheme of things, you are still ignoring what is being asked of you